# There is no move_base node in move_base package

Tags: navigation, move-base, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I am trying to launch move_base, but I am getting such messages:

1. when launching it through launch file:
   `ERROR: cannot launch node of type [move_base/move_base]: can't locate node [move_base] in package [move_base]`
2. when launching it by rosrun:
   `[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named move_base below /opt/ros/indigo/share/move_base
   [rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files,
   [rosrun] or not executable:
   [rosrun]   /opt/ros/indigo/share/move_base`

   The system sees the package move_base, but there is no nodes in it. Other packages and nodes of navigation stack work fine. I use Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine with ROS Indigo. I installed navigation stack with `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-navigation`. My ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is `/home/viki/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks`
    I am very new to ROS, so I have no idea what caused the problem. Please, help me!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207110/there-is-no-move_base-node-in-move_base-package/) by [Dio Eraclea](https://answers.ros.org/users/21681/dio-eraclea/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-04-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not an answer but comment don't seem to work these days :s. Here are some leads to explore:

Can you see move base in the list when you run `ls /opt/ros/indigo/lib/move_base/` ?
If not, this means that move base has not been properly installed. So try:
`sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-move-base` 
then you should see move base in /opt/ros/indigo/lib/move_base/
If yes, run `rospack profile` to update you package list and then you can try to run your node move_base again.

Hope this helps,

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2015-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dio Eraclea](https://answers.ros.org/users/21681/dio-eraclea/) on 2015-04-16**:
Thanks for your answer! I can see move base in those folders. Actually, I fixed the problem, it was in the wrong settings in catkin workspace. After I reset the workspace and modified ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, all was working

**Comment by [wanglan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23987/wanglan/) on 2015-09-22**:
hello! I met the same problem, can you tell me, what exactly do you do?

**Comment by [Dio Eraclea](https://answers.ros.org/users/21681/dio-eraclea/) on 2015-09-29**:
Actually, I do not remember exactly what I did. After that problem I reinstalled Ubuntu several times on different machines and I never got this problem again. I think, that you should look at setting catkin workspace tutorial on roswiki

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2016-05-23**:
I had a similar problem where move_base was not installed (if in doubt type "rospack find move_base" into terminal and it should return the file path if its installed). Running "sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-move-base" fixed the problem for me.

**Comment by [Mr Tai](https://answers.ros.org/users/73015/mr-tai/) on 2021-04-07**:
Thanks. I am ok, so i did't buld node "move_base"

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Running "sudo cp /opt/ros/indigo/lib/move_base/move_base /opt/ros/indigo/share/move_base" fixed the problem for me.

---

Originally posted by [wuming](https://answers.ros.org/users/27096/wuming/) with karma: 41 on 2016-06-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matwilso](https://answers.ros.org/users/27246/matwilso/) on 2017-10-07**:
Confirmed. Had the same problem in kinetic and this fixed it! (replacing indigo with kinetic)

**Comment by [hassamsheikh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/37583/hassamsheikh1/) on 2018-11-12**:
does not work for me. but having same problem